# NSubstitute - Make member return result of a lambda invocation

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

We all know the standard of way of specifying a return value for a substitute:

```
mySubstitute.Method().Returns(myValue);
```

I need myValue to be computed at the point of each invocation though, not just once. Is this possible?

Example:

```
mySubstitute.Method().Returns(() => ComputeValueBasedOnSystemClockAndTheWeather());
```

Of course this won't compile, since `Method()` doesn't really return a lambda.

Comment: Like this? http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/

Comment: actually, this turned out to not be what I needed to do, but this technically speaking answers my question, so if you post an answer I will mark it as accepted!

Comment: Thanks! Although it's a shame it didn't achieve what you wanted. I hope you find your way to what you want.

Comment: Actually, by a stroke of luck I ran into a similar problem later on where this came in handy, so thanks a million!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I popped over to the NSubstitue documentation and saw they had a page for [Return from a function](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/).

> The return value for a call to a property or method can be set to the result of a function. This allows more complex logic to be put into the substitute. Although this is normally a bad practice, there are some situations in which it is useful.

```
calculator
    .Add(Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<int>())
    .Returns(x => (int)x[0] + (int)x[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer:

I need to mock `IDurableEntityContext` and the call to `GetState()`, which have this signature:

`T GetState<T>(Func<T> initializer = null)`

I finally got the method to return whatever the `initializer` is by:

```
var context = Substitute.For<IDurableEntityContext>();

Func<ApiUsageReport> initializer = () => throw new Exception();

context.GetState(Arg.Do<Func<ApiUsageReport>>(f => initializer = f))
       .Returns(_ => initializer());
```